# Дебаг запроса в query builder

Tags: php, kohana

Можно ли как-то вывести ту строку запроса, которая получилась в итоге допустим такого развития событий:

```
$query = DB::update($t)
         ->set($upd)
         ->where( $u , '=', $v)
         ->and_where( $r, '=', $i);
```

Как вывести именно строкой этот запрос (т.е. итог этих всех манипуляций)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вроде как, если верить документации по Kohana, то $query и есть искомая строка запроса.

Можно так же попробовать так:

```
echo DB::update($t)
        ->set($upd)
        ->where( $u , '=', $v)
        ->and_where( $r, '=', $i);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Дей-но.